# Improving Log4J performance and code optimization

Tags: java, log4j

I am tuning my application for optimized performance with log4j and trying out Log4J2AsyncLogger log4J2AsyncLogger=new Log4J2AsyncLogger(); and will migrate to Log4j latest version

"***Log4J2AsyncLogger***" will make any improvements in performance ?

Comment: `if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) { logger.debug(...); }` calls `isDebugEnabled` twice, it's arguably worse from performance standpoint. In most logging systems a given logger is already a singleton, so your first point is unclear to me. Besides, does your logging really that huge of a strain on system performance? I mean, really?

Comment: validating isDebugEnabled at code level helps not to pass string to logger class where debug judgement is done more over when debug is enabled we are ready compromise on slight deviation on logger performance. please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: Most performance sensitive thing about logging is computing log record massage at times where logging at required level is turned off. And I do mean "computing message", not checking whether that level is turned on or off manually. Preferred way to skip message computation is using message with parameters or construct a Java8 supplier for the message string. Both approaches discussed in official Log4j documentation.

Comment: Thanks lot. will check in Log4j official documentation

Answer (score 0):

I moved to log4j 2 in which most of the performance related issues are fixed. Also using mixture of synchronous and asynchronous Loggers for flexible operation.